# How to load and play YouTube video into UIWebView in my iOS app?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

I have a WebView in my iOS app. This webView is loading an web page that contains a youtubeVideo using

```
myWebView.loadHTMLString
```

The YouTube-video appears good but when I click to play, this show the "not available" message.

The video is loaded in the html webPage using amp:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-youtube" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-youtube-0.1.js"></script>

<amp-youtube width="480"
  height="270"
  layout="responsive"
  data-videoid="lBTCB7yLs8Y">
</amp-youtube>
```

I can see that the url request then script load the html with shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate webView function and is the embed url video:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/lBTCB7yLs8Y?enablejsapi=1&amp=1&playsinline=1

When I added a YouTube video into a webView on another app like this, I only need add YouTube url in baseURL and this works correctly...:

```
wk.loadHTMLString("<iframe height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/4CEflj1qQ8M?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;\" width=\"560\"></iframe>", baseURL: URL(string : "www.youtube.com"))
```

How can now play the video correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can by following Youtube iFrame player apis: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this require YTPlayerView outlet and I need load another content too. I need load a complete html into a UIWebView and this html contains YouTube videos and another content...